# How to create random image generator in asp.net mvc project c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, random, generator

I am looking for some solution of the random user image.
I created some image and calling it from database if user has no image.
But i dont like it, it is quite ugly.
Is it exists some random image generator, like here in stackoverflow the the user has no photo.
Please help me!

Thanks and take care,
Ragims

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the algorithm used to generate those little gravatar identicon images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow.com uses Gravatar for user images.  I believe Gravatar will serve up those generated kaleidoscope images whenever the email hash does not match with an account (the user does not have a Gravatar.)

Comment: i think it to complicated to send user on other wesite for creating ouw grawater and load it. it just my opinion.

Comment: The point is you don't have to send them to create a Gravatar.  If you send a hash to Gravatar and the email isn't registered, you will see a randomly-generated "anonymous" image like the ones here on StackOverflow.